# Django login method gives recursion error

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I tried making a custom authentication view that saves the user in the session using `login(request, user)` but it gives me

> maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I tried importing the login method with `from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login` as to not confuse methods, but it still did not work.

Authentication works just fine without the login method, but it doesn't save the user in the session, so it's no use.

Here is the full `views.py` file:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate as django_authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
import json

class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

class Authentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        if not email or not password:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('No credentials provided.'))

        credentials = {
            get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD: email,
            'password': password
        }

        user = django_authenticate(**credentials)

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('Invalid username/password.'))

        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))

        django_login(request, user)
        return (user, None)  # authentication successful

class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, Authentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),
            'auth': str(request.auth),
        }
        return Response(content)

def CheckLoginView(requst):
    current_user = requst.user
    return current_user
```

Here is the traceback:

```
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in raise_uncaught_exception
        raise exc …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in initial
        self.perform_authentication(request) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in perform_authentication
        request.user …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/cnmb10a/rest/auth_api/views.py in authenticate
        django_login(request, user) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in login
    if hasattr(request, 'user'): …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/cnmb10a/rest/auth_api/views.py in authenticate
        django_login(request, user) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in login
    if hasattr(request, 'user'): …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in user
                self._authenticate() …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py in _authenticate
                user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self) …
▶ Local vars
/var/www/cnmb10a/cnmb10a/rest/auth_api/views.py in authenticate
        django_login(request, user) …
▶ Local vars
```

The last 4 methods just repeat over and over again.

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that the `django_login()` function called the `authenticate()` that I wrote, which in turn called `django_login()` again.
The solution was to remove `django_login()` from inside `authenticate()` and add it to `LoginView()`, so it looks like this:

```
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, Authentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),
            'auth': str(request.auth),
        }
        django_login(request, request.user)
        return Response(content)
```

Answer (score 2):

`django.contrib.auth.authenticate` will call the backend to try to authenticate a user.
By calling it in your authentication backend, it will loop forever because `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` will be calling you backend which will call the function and so on.

So you need to hereto from the authentication method your are trying to override and call `super().authenticate(request)` instead of `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`.

Comment: I have tried using `super().authenticate(request)` but it tells me I have to override the method. But I do not believe the `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` method is the problem here, as if I comment out the `django.contrib.auth.login` method, it works, but it doesn't save the user in the session. I have tried your solution with the `login` method, but `super()` has no login method.